# react router redux is not rendered on props changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

I'm struggling on using react router redux and everything is fine except rendering on props changing.

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import App from './app';
import Sign from '../sign/app';
import SignInfo from '../sign/redux/reducer';

let store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    SignInfo,
    routing: routerReducer
  }),
);

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

class Index extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log('root')
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Route path="/" component={App}/>
          <Route path="/sign" component={Sign}/>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Index/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

sign.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Belle from 'belle';
import {Grid, Row, Col} from 'react-flexbox-grid';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import SignPaze1 from './signPaze1'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const mainCardStyle = {
      border: '1px solid #aaa',
    }
    return (

      <div className="sign-page">
        <SignPaze1/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(App));
```

signPaze1.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Belle from 'belle';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import {Grid, Row, Col} from 'react-flexbox-grid';

import {handleSignInput} from './redux/action';

class SignPaze1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleInputValue = this.handleInputValue.bind(this);

  }

  handleInputValue(e) {
    let {dispatch} = this.props;
    console.log('on render')
    const action = bindActionCreators(handleSignInput, dispatch)
    action(e.target.id, e.target.value);
  }
  render() {
    let signData = this.props.signData;
    let mainCardStyle = {
      border: '1px solid #aaa',
    }
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12}>
            <Belle.Card style={mainCardStyle}>
              <Row center="md">
                <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}
                     className="input-group">
                  <input type="text"
                         id="company_number"
                         value={signData.company_number}
                         onChange={this.handleInputValue}/>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}
                     mdOffset={1} lgOffset={2}
                     className="input-group">
                  <Belle.TextInput
                    onUpdate={this.handleInputValue.bind(this, 'data')}/>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <Row center="md">
                <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}
                     className="input-group">
                  <Belle.TextInput
                    onUpdate={this.handleInputValue.bind(this, 'da2')}/>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}
                     mdOffset={1} lgOffset={2}
                     className="input-group">
                  <Belle.TextInput
                    onUpdate={this.handleInputValue.bind(this, 'dat3')}/>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Belle.Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log(state.SignInfo);
  return {
    signData: state.SignInfo.signData,
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(SignPaze1));
```

reducer.js

```
import {HANDLE_SIGN_INPUT} from './action';

const initialMainState = {
  signData: {
    company_number: 'asdas|',
    company_name: '',
    username: '',
    email: '',
    email_confirm: '',
    password: '',
    password_confirm: '',
  }
}

function SignInfo(state = initialMainState, action) {
  let newVal = {};
  switch (action.type) {
    case HANDLE_SIGN_INPUT:
      newVal = Object.assign({}, state);
      newVal.signData[action.target] = action.value;
      return newVal;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default SignInfo;
```

someone says that add `withRouter` function on export line will fix this error, but it doesn't. ([here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4671)). However is normally render again when state which is member of `SignPaze1` is changed.

How can I fix this problem causd by react-router-redux?

**edit**

action.js

```
export const HANDLE_SIGN_INPUT = 'HANDLE_SIGN_INPUT';

export function handleSignInput(target, value){
  return {
    type: HANDLE_SIGN_INPUT,
    target: target,
    value: value,
  }
}
```

Comment: What component is not re-rendered when you are updating what prop?

Comment: @JacobPålsson class `SignPaze1` in signpaze1.js file doesn't render 'again'.(I mean, first time when page is loaded, `SignPaze1` is rendered well, but after props changed, it doesn't.) And I have found `console.log` in `mapStateToProps()` run well but not in `render()` which is member function of `SignPaze1` class.

Comment: can you show your action.js file

Comment: @TomBerghuis I add `action.js` file on my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue here is that you should be using `combineReducers`, instead of a single reducer containing nested objects.

You probably need to create a reducer specifically for `signData`, and use Redux's [`combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) method.

## New file: signDataReducer.js

```
import {HANDLE_SIGN_INPUT} from './action';

const initialMainState = {
  company_number: 'asdas|',
  company_name: '',
  username: '',
  email: '',
  email_confirm: '',
  password: '',
  password_confirm: '',
};

export default function SignData (state = initialMainState, action) {
  let newVal = {};
  switch (action.type) {
    case HANDLE_SIGN_INPUT:
      newVal = Object.assign({}, state);
      newVal[action.target] = action.value;
      return newVal;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

## reducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import signDataReducer from './signDataReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  signDataReducer
});
```

The reason it wasn't working before is because of how `Object.assign` works, it copies the *reference* of `signData` to the new object created by assign.

Then when the `SignPaze1` props are compared by shallow comparison, `signData` is the exact same object as before, so is considered equal. And no render occurs.

i.e.

```
const initialMainState = {
  signData: {
    company_number: 'asdas|',
    company_name: '',
    username: '',
    email: '',
    email_confirm: '',
    password: '',
    password_confirm: '',
  }
}
const newState = Object.assign({}, initialMainState);


newState.signData.company_name = 'Hello!';
// => "Hello!"
initialMainState.signData.company_name
// => "Hello!"
newState.signData === initialMainState.signData
// => true
```